# Integral extension of a complete/Henselian DVR

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

It is known that an integral extension of a complete DVR is again a DVR. Is it also true that an integral extension of an Henselian DVR is again a DVR?

Thanks in advance,
kindasorta

CORRECTION: As Mohan mentioned, the extension of a complete DVR is not a complete DVR but rather "just" a DVR.

Comment: Are you making a mistake in your first sentence? It is not true that such an extension is a DVR.

Comment: I am not unacquainted to saying stupid stuff :)

Comment: For a finite extension $L/Frac(R)$ the *integral closure* of $R$ in $L$ is a complete (or henselian?) DVR. Moreover the valuation is given by $\frac1n v(N_{L/Frac(R)}(a))$. For example $k[[x]][x^{3/2}]$ is a local ring but not a DVR the unique maximal ideal $(x,x^{3/2})$ is not principal

Comment: Interesting, this definitely gives good intuition! Thank you.